# Storing Google API credentials in a database. Is it secure?

Tags: security, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I'm wonderig if storing Google API credentials in a database is secure. Google encourages to do that, for example (google code that stores pickled binary credentials in a database as plain text): https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/contrib/django_util/models.py

So I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

In [Subject: Changes to the Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html) Google asks

> Asking developers to make reasonable efforts to keep their private keys private and not embed them in open source projects.

This just means that you must keep the credentials secure and not share them with people outside your development team.  You can put them on your server (outside of HTTP root is probably best) you can store them in the database.  Where you put them is up to you and your security team.  You just cant give them out.

IMO database is fine